# Trying to stop SpeechSynthesizer in uwp on click of a button

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to stop SpeechSynthesizer in uwp on click of a button  and also trying to start SpeechSynthesizer on clicking same icon again.Any Help would be appreciated for resolution of this issue.
XAML

```
<Image x:Name="Sound" Source="ABCD/sound_active.png"
                   RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                       RelativePanel.RightOf="Pause" Tapped="SoundTap"
                       Margin="17,0,0,0"
                   Width="40" Height="40"/>
```

C# code

```
private void SoundTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            if ((Sound.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource == new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Sound_active.png", UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                Sound.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Sound_mute.png"));                
                textToSpeech.Stop();

            }
            else
            {
                Sound.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Sound_active.png"));
                textToSpeech.Play();
            }
        }

public async void Prevevent(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentIndex--;
            if (currentIndex < 0)
            {
                currentIndex = 0;
                return;
            }
            Alph_cap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Cap_alpha/Cap_" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            Alph_small.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Cap_alpha/Sml_" + currentIndex + ".png"));            
            CapAlphaName.Text = CapsAlpha[currentIndex];
            SmallAlphaName.Text = SmallAlpha[currentIndex];
            var speechText = this.CapAlphaName.Text;
            if (speechText != "")
            {
                var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

                var speechStream =await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(speechText);

                this.textToSpeech.AutoPlay = true;
                this.textToSpeech.SetSource(speechStream, speechStream.ContentType);
                this.textToSpeech.Play();
            }

        }
```

Comment: *"resolution of this issue"* - What *is* the issue?

Comment: If i tap on "Sound" image the SpeechSynthesizer should stop working and if i tap "Sound" image again then SpeechSynthesizer should start working again.I have edit the code where i implement SpeechSynthesizer please see it.

Comment: You just repeated your requirements, but still failed to explain, what the **issue** is.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding the question:

Basically you're looking for a toggle switch to turn on and turn off the speech synthesis tts(Text to Speech) in simpler terms.

---

### The Solution:

This couldn't have been simpler enough, never the less, this is how you do it.

1. Create a `Bool` property, eg: `private IsTTSEnabled = false` we'll use this as a flag.
2. On your Image tap or click, check the current value of IsTTSEnabled and flip it (false if true or true if false)  eg: `IsTTSEnable = !IsTTSEnable;`
3. Now put a if loop for handling if the TTS is turned on or if it's turned off. Also, since TTS is done using a media element, you don't need to reInitialize your TTS, simple pause and play your media element or start and Stop it as per needs.

So your c# code becomes:

```
    private bool IsTTSEnabled = false;
    private void SoundTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsTTSEnabled = !IsTTSEnabled;
        if(IsTTSEnabled)
        {
            Sound.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Sound_mute.png"));
            textToSpeech.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            Sound.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Sound_active.png"));
            textToSpeech.Play();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This functionality can be easily implemented using Data Binding to provide scalability and ease of management but then the simpler way to do so is like the one I've illustrated